# Selecting Listview multi items?

Tags: arrays, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have created a ListView with foods. I would like to select many items and that it store SQLite table with the information of selected item. How can do this using Xamarin.Android? Please tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Sorry for the poor english)

To implement multiselections you must handle it in the object (list item) itself.

[This recipe](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/multiselect/) may help you.

Comment: First of all thanks for your comment. And also, so sorry for my bad English. However, I have the SQLite database and store food details. Now food data load for ListView. Then we can select many items. Now I wanted to know about how can get selecting item details.

Comment: It's exactly what that recipe I've mentioned teaches you. Here is the sample code: https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/tree/master/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/Controls/multiselect

Comment: thanks your comment and I refer it and get the idea.

Comment: https://diptimayapatra.wordpress.com/2013/07/10/xamarin-get-selected-items-from-listview-in-android/

Comment: this link refers and we can get a basic idea how can solve this problem. very help full. Thanks all    REFER --> https://diptimayapatra.wordpress.com/2013/07/10/xamarin-get-selected-items-from-listview-in-android/